# How to simplify this combinatorial expression?

Tags: co.combinatorics

$f(m,n)=\binom{m}{m}\binom{n}{1}+\binom{m}{m-1}\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+\binom{m}{2}\binom{n}{m-1}+\binom{m}{1}\binom{n}{m}=?$

Can we simplify the expression above?

Comment: This type of expression is very well known. See Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik, particularly table 174 (p. 174). 

Comment: (I should have paused; this looks like homework.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_identity